# React app crashes with react-scripts error "no such file or directory"

Tags: reactjs, node.js, caching, node-modules

I try to work on my React app, but it crashes at a random moment. It can be 2 minutes after the app was started or after 30 minutes or after 2 hours.

I use MacOS Sonoma and Node v18.17.0.

Here is the error

`webpack compiled with 1 warning
.../project/frontend/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:19
throw err;
^

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '.../project/frontend/node_modules/.cache/default-development/5.pack'] {
errno: -2,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'stat',
path: '.../project/frontend/node_modules/.cache/default-development/5.pack'
}

Node.js v18.17.0
`

Thanks for any help!

I've tried to uninstall 2 node modules I had before the issue occured: deep-equal and react-pdf.
Also I've tried to clear my cache using npm cache clean --force.
That didn't help